# Explain Java Generic Modifying Standard Type

Tags: java, generics, methods

This signature:

```
public static <E extends Enum<E>> String getEnumString(Class<E> clazz, String s)
```

is not found anywhere I could see in the Oracle Java documentation for Generics. It appears to use a generic typecast of the returned String value but that cannot be since a real string is returned. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Referencing the answer to this thread: [Java: Generic method for Enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16406298/java-generic-method-for-enums)

The method:

```
public static <E extends Enum<E>>String getEnumString(Class<E> clazz, String s){
  for(E en : EnumSet.allOf(clazz)){
    if(en.name().equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
      return en.name();
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: I cannot make out the question you are asking?

Comment: What exactly is <E extends Enum<E>> ? I have never seen a signature like access, modifier, generic-qualifier, return type, method(){} . Collection<> I get, but not this.

Answer (score 2):

The construction

```
<E extends Enum<E>> String getEnumString(...
```

is not a *"Generic Modifying Standard Type"*.

It is a declaration of a type parameter (the `<E extends Enum<E>>`) followed by the return type of the method and its arguments.  It specifies that the method is generic and provides a type parameter and its bounds.

The type parameter does not modify `String` at all.  It declares a bounded type parameter `E` that is used later in the argument list at `Class<E> clazz` to specify that the set of acceptable `Class` instances is limited to enumeration types.

Comment: Got it, thank you very much. Very nice. I missed it, docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html